# Retrieve upcoming invoice with disposable prices

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to preview the upcoming invoice using disposable prices. The user (sales team) can input any price they want for the product, and a table with the upcoming invoice is displayed and refreshed with each change in the input.

Since Prices are resources that we can't delete, is there a way to use temp/disposable prices valid only on the `invoices.retrieveUpcoming` request?

Edit:

I don't want to create a Price that will not be used at all. Think that the user can input any value at any time, and for each new value, I create a new price just to get the upcoming invoice.

Answer (score 0):

The Retrieve Upcoming Invoice [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming) has the `subscription_items` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming#upcoming_invoice-subscription_items) which itself contains the `price_data` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming#upcoming_invoice-subscription_items-price_data) allowing you to pass dynamic pricing as needed without having to create the Price upfront. It mirrors what the Create Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create) offers.

Comment: Yes, that parameter allows creating a price inline. But I don't want to create a Price object because it probably won't be used.

Comment: Have you tried the call though? It doesn't create the Price in the API, it just uses the information to simulate it in the upcoming invoice.